# Auditing GPO with Powershell

Tags: powershell

So there are a whole variety of cmdlets to work with GPO in Powershell. Essentially I would like to add a GPO audit to an existing audit script but want to create a folder per GPO object, i.e. based on each GPO name.

Essentially I would like to run a t`Get-GPOReport` on all GPO's, but dump each HTML report into a sub folder of GPO Audit. i.e. `GPO Audit\GPO1\GPO1Report.html` etc.

I assuming I need to do something of sort like:

```
$gpoArray = Get-GPO -All -Domain "domain.local"
```

Then create a loop:

```
ForEach($gpo in $gpoArray)..
```

And then run a `Get-GPOReport` to each GPO name in the array, but my query is, how do I define out the name of the GPO, something like, `$gpo.Name` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close. It's **$gpo.DisplayName**.

You can always use **Get-Member** to get all the properties and methods of an object. Since **Get-GPO** is returning an *array* of objects representing GPO's, just pipe the first element to **Get-Member**:

```
$gpoArray[0] | Get-Member
```